# Where like not working inside foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Where like not working inside foreach loop in Laravel. The following always return `null`. Here i want to use multi sorting, but the response in always blank.

```
public function searchBy(Request $request)
{ 
    if($request->name!=''){ 
       $data['name']=$request->name;
    }

    if($request->s_name!=''){
       $data['short_name']=$request->s_name;
    }

    if($request->pin!=''){
        $data['pin_code']=$request->pin;
    }

    if($request->city!=''){
       $data['city']=$request->city;
    }

    $customers = Customer::get();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // return $key;
       $customers = $customers->where($key,'LIKE','%'.$value.'%');
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' =>$customers,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to format better the code

Comment: Why like inside foreach ?. If table contains more data then you got time out just use query to search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The variable `$customers` should be a `QueryBuilder` and you should call get() on it in the end to retrieve your items.

```
$customers = Customer::query();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $customers->where($key,'LIKE','%'.$value.'%');
}

return response()->json([
    'data' => $customers->get(),
]);
```

The QueryBuilder is an object, which is by design pass by reference, therefor you do not need to reassign it.